# How to resolve grub-probe error: disk lvmid/xxx not found

Tags: grub2, lvm, rsync, chroot

I encounter an error stating "lvmid not found" when running the grub-probe command.

```
# grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /
grub-probe: error: disk `lvmid/R9xUrf-ONd8-wCXx-qfxt-m5Ox-JwKG-LrcAZI/TKMrA6-U6Ex-mjxI-CfF4-Wjdn-HDtv-d15mYq' not found.
```

Objective:

I want to switch the disk mounted on the root partition from ubuntu-lv (LV) to ubuntu-tlv (thin LV) and boot from ubuntu-tlv (thin LV).

Although I have achieved my objective using the two methods below, I still encounter the error "grub-probe: error: disk lvmid/xxx' not found" when running grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /`. I would like to know:

1. The cause of the error
2. How to resolve the error
3. Which file is being referenced when checking the lvmid in grub-probe

Copying data from ubuntu-lv to ubuntu-tlv via rsync

```
# create: ubuntu-tlv, 01_os-installed
lvcreate -TL 500G ubuntu-vg/pool
lvcreate -TV 100G -n ubuntu-tlv ubuntu-vg/pool
lvcreate -sl 100%ORIGIN -n 01_os-installed /dev/ubuntu-vg/

# rsync: 01_os-installed -> ubuntu-tlv
mkfs.ext4 /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-tlv
mkdir -p /mnt/ubuntu-tlv
mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-tlv /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/
mkdir -p /mnt/01_os-installed
mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/01_os-installed /mnt/01_os-installed/
rsync -zahP /mnt/01_os-installed/ /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/
```

Method 1: Using rsync to copy data from ubuntu-lv to ubuntu-tlv

```
# generate: grub.cfg
tlv_dmpath=$(dmsetup info -c --noheadings -o name ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-tlv)
tlv_blkid=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-tlv)
echo "GRUB_DEVICE=\"${tlv_dmpath}\"" > /etc/default/grub.d/ubuntu-tlv.cfg
echo "GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=\"${tlv_blkid}\"" >> /etc/default/grub.d/ubuntu-tlv.cfg
\cp -a /etc/default/grub.d/ubuntu-tlv.cfg /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/etc/default/grub.d/
update-grub

# apply
reboot
cat /proc/cmdline
grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /
# Here, grub-probe: error: disk `lvmid/xxx' not found occurs
```

Method 2: Booting from ubuntu-tlv (thin LV) after chroot

```
# chroot
mount --bind /dev /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/sys
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu-tlv/boot/efi
chroot /mnt/ubuntu-tlv

# generate: grub.cfg
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sda
exit

# apply
reboot
cat /proc/cmdline
grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /
# Here, grub-probe: error: disk `lvmid/xxx' not found occurs
```

Additional Information:

- I have successfully mounted ubuntu-tlv as the root partition and can boot from it.
- The id lvmid/R9xUrf-d15mYq does exist and corresponds to ubuntu-tlv.
- There doesn't seem to be any reference to R9xUrf-d15mYq in the grub.cfg file.

```
# dmsetup info -c --noheadings -o name,uuid /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-*
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv:LVM-R9xUrfONd8wCXxqfxtm5OxJwKGLrcAZIx5cahFfWJYaHao3WgG8GtSoEo187T0Z6
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--tlv:LVM-R9xUrfONd8wCXxqfxtm5OxJwKGLrcAZITKMrA6U6ExmjxICfF4WjdnHDtvd15mYq

# lvs
  LV              VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin    Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  01_os-installed ubuntu-vg swi-a-s--- 100.39g      ubuntu-lv 0.46
  pool            ubuntu-vg twi-aotz-- 500.00g                2.62   11.28
  ubuntu-lv       ubuntu-vg owi-a-s--- 100.00g
  ubuntu-tlv      ubuntu-vg Vwi-aotz-- 100.00g pool           13.12

# df -hT
Filesystem                         Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              tmpfs  3.2G  1.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--tlv ext4    98G   11G   83G  12% /
tmpfs                              tmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              tmpfs  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          ext4   2.0G  130M  1.7G   8% /boot
/dev/sda1                          vfat   1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              tmpfs  3.2G  4.0K  3.2G   1% /run/user/0
```